# Save a facebook app. configuration type

Tags: facebook

I would love to know if it is already possible to save a facebook app. configuration type and apply this configuration type to other facebook applications.
Kind regards.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Currently there is no way to "export" application settings. Furthermore there is currently no way to import settings into an application.

Comment: Lix, thank you for your quick response. I hope that this option will come soon.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Selenium or Greasemonkey: record & generate an app -> easy copying

Comment: Tanks, this solution is ingenious but not professional in my opinion.

Comment: @nic - if the feature is not provided and we are forced to make our own methods, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Professional software is tested by Selenium so why do not use it for other automation purposes.